# Is get or basename() more efficient?

Tags: php, get, url-parsing

which of the following is more efficient?

1. Using a get function on a token (random), for example:

   `http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory?value=random
   $_GET['value']`
2. Make the token part of the URL and parse it, for example:

   `$url="http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory/random"
   basename($url)`

And actually, is basename more efficient than using explode or `substr(strrchr())`?

Comment: Please stop trying to optimize things that do not need to be optimized.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" (and so on). I promise you, that you will never feel any difference between both. Choose the one, that fits into your application (design), not the one, that may save one or two cpu cycles.

Comment: Following the comments above, if you are interested in determining the efficiency/performance of a block of code compared to another at this *low* level you can always benchmark it yourself.

Comment: @ThiefMaster & @KingCrunch I fully understand your sentiment. On the websites I built in the past, I didn't worry about minor optimization such as this. However, I am always trying to improve my skills and hope that one day I will end up building a website that will require such minor optimization :-)  @Jason McCreary I will in the future. At the time, I didn't know how to benchmark the performance. jcinacio provided me with such a method in the selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_GET is obviously more efficient, since it doesn't compute anything

Still, unless you plan on calling that a few thousand times in your script, it's negligible so use whatever you feel works better.

```
$t = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $x = basename($url);
}
printf("%.3f\n", microtime(true) - $t);
```

> 0.010

Comment: testing basename function? WTF

Comment: I don't know why this would get a down vote. Even though I know that $_GET would be faster, I still ran a test to see how much. over 1mil iterations, accessing $_GET took ~.2 seconds, basename took ~2 seconds. Pretty much proving what I already knew, that it doesn't matter, because when it comes down to calling either one a few times you are talking fractions of a millisecond. There are other bottlenecks that would be better optimized than to worry about this.

Comment: @yes123: i fail to see your point. **anything** can be tested, why not?

Comment: Thanks! You answered the question and provided a way for me to test it myself.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn Thanks for actually testing it for me!

Answer (score 2):

Use `basename`. There is no need to make another function that you already have.

Also in this case performance is completly insignificant

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't sweat micro-optimizations.
2. If you want to sweat micro-optimizations, it's pretty trivial to test #1 vs #2 yourself.
3. Regardless of minimal performance differences, #2 is generally preferred because you get a friendly URL.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep #3 in mind for future websites as better looking URLs makes sense as a reason to choose the basename option.  However, for the website on which I am currently working, I'm looking for pure optimization.